# UISplitViewController delegate methods only called sometimes

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am using the following delegate methods to add and remove a "popover" menu, so when the device is rotated either way, the menu is shown or not shown:

```
-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController*)pc {
    // Show popover button
}

-(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem{
    // Hide popover button
}
```

This is done as per the [apple documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/iPadControllers/iPadControllers.html). Sometimes when I start my application the popover button is not shown, ie the "willHideViewController" method is not called, are we supposed to be adding the code to show the popover in another location as well?